# How to find the largest contour?

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I have written a script in **python** that utilises the **max()** method, I am trying to recreate a similar program in c++ but I am having trouble obtaining the value for the largest contour in a mask.

I have tried to use the **max_element()** function from the algorithm library in C++ but to no avail. I have also tried to dereference the iterator but receive a series of errors, here is my code:

```
if (contours.size() > 0)
{
    c = *max_element(contours.begin(), contours.end());
    //not compiling
}
```

Here is the error:

```
no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point_<int> > >' and 'std::vector<cv::Point_<int> >')
```

Here is how I do it in Python:

```
if len(contours) > 0;
        #find largest contour in mask, use to compute minEnCircle 
        c = max(contours, key = cv2.contourArea)
        (x,y), radius) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)
        M = cv2.moments(c)
```

Comment: What is the type of `contours`!? C++ is statically typed, that's how the validity of an operation is determined.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: std::vector<vector<cv::Point> > contours;

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your Python example you are passing a comparator as the `key` argument

```
c = max(contours, key = cv2.contourArea)
```

The equivalent of doing this is to pass a comparator to `std::max_element` as well

```
auto c = *std::max_element(contours.begin(),
                           contours.end(),
                           [](std::vector<cv::Point> const& lhs, std::vector<cv::Point> const& rhs)
          {
              return contourArea(lhs, false) < contourArea(rhs, false);
          });
```

In this case `c` will be of type `std::vector<cv::Point>` which represents a contour.

Comment: typenames are ok ;D

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply, I tried to compile this however received an error stating " 'auto' changes meaning in c++11; please remove it".

Comment: After compiling without 'auto' I receive an error stating " lamba expressions only available with -std=c++11 or std-gnu++11.

Comment: Did you previously define the variable `c`? If so, it needs to be declared `std::vector<cv::Point>`, then you can remove the `auto` within your `if` block. Yes lambdas are only available in C++11 or later, if you are using a previous compiler version you can [write a functor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356950/c-functors-and-their-uses) instead which will act the same way.

Comment: Thank you for the illumination upon functors!! I am using gcc-4.9 on Qt and so I discovered that I needed to amend my .pro file to include the line "QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11" . Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I assume the collection is a nested vector of points according to what `findContours` function from OpenCV requires.

In such case you can see an example of the solution: [Find Biggest Contour Using C++](http://harismoonamkunnu.blogspot.de/2013/06/opencv-find-biggest-contour-using-c.html)

Basically you call `contourArea` to acquire the actual area taken by the contour,  or `boundingRect` alternatively `minAreaRect` to determine the area a contour can be enclosed with. Depends on what you actually require.